# Do you have a right to your own reference check conducted by a third-party?

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate

You apply through an estate agency for a house and pay them a fee to conduct a reference check. This reference check is then done by a third-party with which you interact with.

In the UK, do you have a right to see this reference check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes

The UK is still a member of the EU and subject to GDPR.

The third-party is keeping personal data on you and you have a right to know what it is.